# Simple jquery ajax php request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, call

I am doing a basic jquery ajax call on a php file and can't seemsto figure out why it isn't working. Any help is appreciated. Fiebug does not seem to show any ajax or XHR action going on. I want to not to refresh the page and just execute the ajax call. Thanks.

JS

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
function getData(url_param){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'data.php',
        data: {url_param:url_param},      
        success: function(data) {
            $('#data').html(data);        
        }
    });
};

$('#clickMe').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    getData(2);
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div><a id='clickMe' href='data.php?url_param=url_param'>CLICK ME TO RUN PHP</a></div>
<div id="data"></div>  <!-- divto show result -->
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_GET['url_param']){
    echo "simple ajax call";
} 

?>
```

Comment: `getGata` is not a function.

Comment: getGata /= getData ^^

Comment: Is it possible the href is conflicting with the onClick?  I think you could remove the href from the anchor altogether and just have the onClick do an AJAX call

Comment: thanks for the corrections. i made changes to the typo, but no headway yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the event inside an onload function. The most common practice is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#clickMe').click(function(e){
       ...
  });

});
```

You should also add `return false;` in the last line of your event.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have misspelled your function name (**getGata != getData**).

Secondly:

```
data: {url_param:url_param}
```

Are you setting the javascript variable **url_param** anywhere? The $.ajax **data** parameter is formatted as follows:

```
get/post variable name : get/post variable value
```

As you have it now, it doesn't seem that you are assigning a value to **url_param**.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use jQuery post function.

```
$.post('data.php',{param1:'your param 1', param2 : 'your param 2'}, function(response){
    //do your operation here. response is what you get from data.php. 'json' spicifies that the response is json type
    $("#data").html(response);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

The (amended?) JavaScript prevents your code from working, because you haven't closed the angle brackets on jQuery source, it should be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One of the comments states you shouldn't have the href in the anchor, but because you've ignored defaults this isn't triggered (assuming JS is enabled in the user's browser).

Finally, I think that

```
return false;
```

should really be inside the function after

```
getData(2);
```

but since we're ignoring defaults, the anchor shouldn't make an attempt to go anywhere or reload anyway.